# Handling "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

so I'm learning Java for the first time. The following code throws a `NullPointer` exception when `square.toString()` is called in another class (where square is an instance of the object defined in this class), and I'm a little foggy about why this doesn't work. Can someone explain that to me?

```java
public class SquareBuilder {

String box;
String[] parts;
final private String beam = "----";
final private String collumn = "|";
private int size;

public SquareBuilder(int firstSize)
{
    size = firstSize;

}

public static String repeatString(String s, int n) 
{   
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        sb.append(s);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}

public void changeSize(int newSize)
{
    size = newSize;

}

public String toString( )
{
        parts[0] = repeatString(beam,size) + "\n";
        parts[1] = collumn + repeatString(" ",4*size-2) + collumn + "\n";
        box = parts[0] + repeatString(parts[1],size-2) + parts[0];
    return box;

}
}
```

Comment: What's the full stack trace of your exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A NullPointerException comes when you attempt to use methods on a null object.  You should, in your constructor, initialize the `parts` array using the expression

`parts = new String[whateverSizeYouWant];`

It is not clear to me what you are doing with the array.

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear why you've declared an *instance* variable called `parts` which you then dereference (`parts[0] = ...`) in `toString()` - but you're never initializing it, so the value is `null`... hence the exception.

Why is your implementation not just:

```
public String toString( )
{
    String ends = repeatString(beam,size) + "\n";
    String middle = collumn + repeatString(" ",4*size-2) + collumn + "\n";
    return ends + middle + ends;
}
```

It's *very* unusual to want to modify an object in `toString()`.

Comment: I had arrays on the brain for some reason, obviously no reason to use them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not framed properly, however i guess that you are getting an NPE in your toString() method. Reason is you never really initialized your array `String[] parts;` in your code.

You have to initialize it first:

```
public SquareBuilder(int firstSize)
{
    size = firstSize;
    this.parts = new int[give the size here];

}
```